# OS X Web View App - Won't Load Local .html Web Page

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

I have the following code in an AppDelegate.m file that opens Google when I open my app. I am trying to change it to open a .HTML web page I copied into my Xcode project but it is not working. I am using Xcode 4.5.2.

The code that works to open Google is:

```
@implementation MDAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
    [self.webView.mainFrame loadRequest:request];
}
```

I tried changing it to (so that it would load my test.html file I put in the project folder but the app just comes up blank now). What am I missing?

```
@implementation MDAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"test.html"]];
    [self.webView.mainFrame loadRequest:request];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your `test.html` is copied at the root of your project (make sure it's also copied to your final app bundle, huh? - check *Build Phases*) you can load it up your Web View using this code :

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[self.webView.mainFrame loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: @user1822824 Glad to have helped! ;-)

Comment: Is there a simple way to enable local storage for the web view?

Comment: @user1822824 What do you mean by *local storage*?

Answer (score 1):

`[NSURL URLWithString:@"test.html"]` is not creating a valid URL to your file. Try that: (it is from an iOS project, but should apply to OS X apps as well). I'm using `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` instead of `loadRequest:`

```
NSString* fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fileName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSURL *baseURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Comment: How would I reference test.html if it's copied to the root of my project?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean? How does the code you included reference test.html? Or do I add the code you included in addition to what I have?

Comment: well, because it is my code, it references error.html. I'll change it to use test.html if that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"test.html"]
```

There's your problem. Assuming that your `test.html` file is in the resource folder of your application bundle, do this instead:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"html"];
```

NSBundle has a few other methods for easily creating URLs in case the one above isn't appropriate (like if the file is in a subdirectory). Take a look at the [NSBundle reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.